# Windows 10 Universal App Navigating between pages VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, navigation, win-universal-app

Looking at various sources across the internet I have found that

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof (SecondaryPage))
```

Seems to be the method of switching pages. However, I get an error on 'SecondaryPage' Saying: SecondaryPage is a class type and cannot be used in this expression. Any Ideas?

I need navigation between a few pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that inspecting the App.vb provided the answer. I looked into how the app automatically loaded the first page.

In VB.NET it is

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(SecondaryPage))
```

Comment: See also [GetType and TypeOf confusion](http://blogs.msmvps.com/joacim/2009/08/31/gettype-and-typeof-confusion/)

Comment: This is fantastic, Thanks for sharing this. I come from a C# background and I'm still getting over the VB Quirks